# less than in embedded document (mongoDB)

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

Good afternoon, how could I look for "Precios" under 200 in all the documents in my collection?

I am trying to use the query:

```
db.tienda.find ( { "Productos.Precio": { $lte: 200 } } )
```

The structure of my document is:

```
use tienda

db.tienda.insert( [
{ 
 "Codigo": 1, "Nombre": "Fabrica comida", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "C1", "Nombre": "Papitas", "Precio": 1.20 }, { 
 "Codigo": "C2", "Nombre": "Perro caliente", "Precio": 3.10 }, { "Codigo": 
 "C3", "Nombre": "Hamburguesa", "Precio": 4 }, { "Codigo": "C4", "Nombre": 
 "Pizza", "Precio": 2.60 }, { "Codigo": "C5", "Nombre": "Malteada", 
 "Precio": 3 } ] 
},
{ 
 "Codigo": 2, "Nombre": "Tecnologia", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "T1", "Nombre": "Producto 8", "Precio": 300 }, { 
 "Codigo": "T2", "Nombre": "Smart TV", "Precio": 1200 }, { "Codigo": "T3", 
 "Nombre": "Teatro en casa", "Precio": 250 }, { "Codigo": "T4", "Nombre": 
 "Laptop", "Precio": 560 }, { "Codigo": "T5", "Nombre": "DVD", "Precio": 160 
 } ] 
},
{ 
 "Codigo": 3, "Nombre": "Deportes", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "D1", "Nombre": "Balon de futbol", "Precio": 20 
 }, { "Codigo": "D2", "Nombre": "Bate de baseball", "Precio": 49.99 }, { 
 "Codigo": "D3", "Nombre": "Canilleras", "Precio": 7.80 }, { "Codigo": "D4", 
 "Nombre": "Equipo de buceo", "Precio": 650 }, { "Codigo": "D5", "Nombre": 
 "Raqueta de tenis", "Precio": 25.50 } ] 
},
{ 
 "Codigo": 4, "Nombre": "Muebles", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "M1", "Nombre": "Armario", "Precio": 330 }, { 
 "Codigo": "M2", "Nombre": "Mesa de centro", "Precio": 60 }, { "Codigo": 
 "M3", "Nombre": "Comedor", "Precio": 1090 }, { "Codigo": "M4", "Nombre": 
 "Sala-Comedor", "Precio": 860 }, { "Codigo": "M5", "Nombre": "Lampara", 
 "Precio": 40 } ] 
},
{ 
 "Codigo": 5, "Nombre": "Hobbies", 
 "Productos": [ { "Codigo": "H1", "Nombre": "Mesa de hockey", "Precio": 320 
 }, { "Codigo": "H2", "Nombre": "Mesa de ping-pong", "Precio": 610 }, { 
 "Codigo": "H3", "Nombre": "Mesa de billar", "Precio": 2400 }, { "Codigo": 
 "H4", "Nombre": "Consola de videojuegos", "Precio": 220 }, { "Codigo": 
 "H5", "Nombre": "Mesa de poker", "Precio": 1650 } ] 
}
] )
```

Any idea what the way of executing the query would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework's [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to specify your condition on nested array:

```
db.tienda.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         Nombre: 1,
         Codigo: 1,
         Productos: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$Productos",
               as: "p",
               cond: { $lte: [ "$$p.Precio", 200 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```